# Why does a device show up as hidraw instead of hiddev?

Tags: drivers, linux-kernel, devices, hid

I read the kernel documentation for hidraw and hiddev, and I understand the differences, but I am wondering how the kernel decides whether or not a device should show up as `/dev/hidraw*` or `/dev/usb/hiddev*`

Answer (score 2):

It's passed as a parameter per driver to `hid_hw_start()`/`hid_connect()`. E.g:

```
hid-thingm.c:   err = hid_hw_start(hdev, HID_CONNECT_HIDRAW);
```

I guess that most drivers do something like this:

```
hid-logitech-dj.c:  retval = hid_hw_start(hdev, HID_CONNECT_DEFAULT);
```

And `HID_CONNECT_DEFAULT` includes `HID_CONNECT_HIDRAW`:

```
#define HID_CONNECT_DEFAULT     (HID_CONNECT_HIDINPUT|HID_CONNECT_HIDRAW| \
                HID_CONNECT_HIDDEV|HID_CONNECT_FF)
```

The exact same thing happens for both `hidraw` and `hiddev`.